# Grunt-usemin doesn't update reference to html template

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm trying to update the template urls in the js files with usemin patterns to prevent caching errors on version change.

When I change `filerev` to following, it renames all the templates, which is exactly what I want.

```
 filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/**/*.html'
        ]
      }
    },
```

But I can't update the urls even though I tried to configure `usemin` for that.

```
usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'],
        patterns:{
          js:[
              [/(views\/.*?\.(html))/gm, 'Update template urls in the js files']
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to that? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have used a workaround. I set a version specific query parameter on angular with a http interceptor. Basically it adds a parameter like this to url of each request "?version=313jkf1f". I don't know if it's ideal, but it prevents caching on new releases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried similar configuration and it didn't work at all.

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets'],
    patterns: {
      js: [
        [/(views\/.*?\.(html))/gm, 'Update template urls in the js files']
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that I added:

```
js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.js']
```

Then I realised that `usemin` is triggered after `requirejs:dist`, which in my case creates the `main.js`, combined and minified. Hope someone is missing that as well :)